# There is no system images at Virtual Device Configuration even I installed Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

There is no system images at Virtual Device Configuration even I installed Android Studio SDK Manager.

[installed on Android Sdk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SVtYL.png)

[no system images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjERK.png)

As you can see from pictures, does not seeing system images.

I run as administrator. Nothing changed.

I tried everything that written here.